# Problem with colorbox playing swf files from amazon S3

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, amazon-s3

Just put our new site live, and having trouble with one of the swf files playing. 
Using the colorbox jquery plugin throughout the site and this works fine.

However a movie on http://www.learningassistant.com/qcf (qcf engine movie) gives out a repeated javascript 'Access is denied' error everytime you close the colorbox??

Perhaps because the swf file is hosted on amazon s3, although other movies are playing fine from S3, example: http://www.learningassistant.com/case-studies/

Somebody help? Doing my head in now!

Answer (score 0):

Might need a crossdomain.xml file on S3 ?